# Apache Camel default data format for a component

Tags: json, apache, routes, apache-camel, activemq-classic

How to set default data format for a component in Apache Camel?

I have a number of routes interacting with different ActiveMQ queues. At the moment all of them look like

```
from("...")
    .process(...)
    .marshal().json() // (1)
    .to("activemq:queue:...");
```

or

```
from("activemq:queue:...")
    .unmarshal().json() // (2)
    .process(...)
    .to("...");
```

1. I would like to replace lines (1) and (2) with either component or context level configuration. Basically saying only once 'message payload going through ActiveMQ has to be a JSON string'.
2. I don't like to add any additional routes, processors, headers, URI parameters, etc.
3. Ideally, it would be applicable for other components and formats besides ActiveMQ and JSON

Comment: You can take a look at interceptors, where you can have from and sent-to: http://camel.apache.org/intercept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using interceptors (Based on Claus Ibsen's comment)

```
new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        // interceptors
        interceptSendToEndpoint("activemq:queue:*")
            .marshal()
            .json();

        interceptFrom("activemq:queue:*")
            .unmarshal()
            .json();

        // routes
        from("...")
            .process(...)
            .to("activemq:queue:...");

        from("activemq:queue:...")
            .process(...)
            .to("...");
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. interceptors have to be defined before any routes in `RouteBuilder`. Otherwise `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown explaining situation.
2. interceptors are not shared and have to be defined in each `RouteBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You could marshall/unmarshall **using a named reference to a data format** that you can define once (here as "myDefaultFormat") in your Camel Registry:

```
from("activemq:queue:...")
.unmarshal(myDefaultFormat)
```

This way, you dont have to repeat .json() everywhere
(but ok, you have yet to repeat the named reference :-$ )

Comment: How do you name a dataformat?  What does your data format definition look like?